# Transmit Pythonscript-Result to Webpage

Tags: python, post, networking, network-programming, webserver

**Actual situation:**

The client downloads a small pythonscript that is executable.
The client executes it. The script gathers information from the computer and sends the data to the webserver vià POST-Method.

**Wanted Situation:**

After the webserver recived the data, it should forward the information to the website-session of the client. And the website should display the information.

This is a visual example of the principle:

[image: Example principle]

There is also a example of this principle on *[Can You Run It](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyria)*.

How can I realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of implementing this is using a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Basically the API does not care if the request is from a script or web browser, it just passes data structures to and from clients. The only tricky part to your example is when there are multiple users involved because a secret must be shared between the browser and script. I believe *Can You Run It* puts this unique secret into the program they ask you to download.

Look into [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for examples of how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As a secret, could a cookie with a sessionId or a other unique Id solve it? And then it would be necessary to give the ID with the exe file?

Comment: As long as it is a cryptographically sound key and it is attached to the message to the web server it will work. It can be attached via cookie (HTTP Header), a JSON value in the POST, in the URL of the GET, it does not matter. No matter the method, the key still must be shared. The browser and script cannot easily speak to each other, that is why it is probably easiest to embed the key in the script when downloaded from the browser. (disclaimer: you could technically also look at the source IP address instead of using a key, but that probably wont work in complex networks.)